# Spark dataset: Combine all the join results by key

Tags: apache-spark, join, apache-spark-dataset

I have two datasets that are to be joined and combine the results for the same key.

Example:

Dataset 1:
key1, value1
key2, value2
key3, value3

Dataset 2:
key1, value4
key4, value5
key1, value6

An inner join using joinWith operation on these 2 datasets will provide me:

Joined dataset:
Tuple2<< key1, value1>, >
Tuple2<< key1, value1>, >

I want to combine all the results for key1 in the left tuple and generate something like:

Tuple2<, List{< key1, value4 >, < key1, value6 >}>

To achieve this, I can:

- joinWith
- groupByKey
- reduceGroups

As groupBy is a costly operation, is there another way I can achieve this?

Comment: What you try to do is costly no matter how you approach it (requires full shuffle and amount of memory bounded by the size of input in the worst case scenario). How you'll approach that, won't change these properties.

Comment: I understand that but in few cases like using reduceByKey instead of groupByKey can optimize the time it takes to complete the operation and I was looking for such ideas.

Comment: [This is](https://github.com/awesome-spark/spark-gotchas/blob/master/04_rdd_actions_and_transformations_by_example.md#be-smart-about-groupbykey) interesting lecture.